# get average of sum of the date difference in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have transaction table like this:

```
transactID           Locid       vtid        dtime                    Paydate
20                   5           7           2013-05-07 17:40:42.000  2013-05-07 17:55:42.000
21                   5           7           2013-05-07 18:15:17.000  2013-05-07 18:25:17.000
22                   5           7           2013-05-07 18:27:44.000  2013-05-07 18:47:44.000
23                   5           8           2013-05-08 12:53:54.000  2013-05-08 13:05:24.000
24                   5           8           2013-05-08 13:11:21.000  2013-05-08 16:53:03.000
```

I wrote the query like this to get `SUM` of datediffernce:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(hour,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)))+':'   +convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)% 60)) + ':'
 +convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)% 60)) 
AS ' HH:MM:SS'
FROM Transaction_tbl t  
WHERE t.Locid=5 
GROUP by vtid
```

Now I am getting output as sum of datediffence:
 HH:MM:SS
    3:44:73
    1:8:67
I want to get the output as average of this value .I mean the first answer(3:44:73) is the sum of vitd 7,instead of getting `SUM` I want to get `average` of sum, here total 3 times vtid 7 is repeating. So answer divide by 3.
Is there any way to do get average like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select SUM(DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)) as sum_min,
       AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0), DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ) ) as avg_min
from Transaction_tbl t where t.Locid=5
group by t.vtid
```

Comment: this is showing wrong answer. sum is showing correct,but avg_date is showing wrong

Comment: that example vtid 7, 3 times and vtid 8,2 times,so 30 should divided by 3 and 8 should divide by 2,like that am gusiing out put

Comment: No.What i am expected

Comment: If values used for `AVG` are `INT`egers then the result's data type will be, also, an integer. And `DATEDIFF` function returns an [integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Comment: while executing this query average of vtid 7 is getting proper. average of vtid 8 is not getting proper.

Comment: I am getting out put like this:

Comment: sory sir,by mistake i said that.this is working fine.thanks for your great help.I Shall be very thank full to you

Comment: sir,,,can i ask one more doubt regarding this:

Comment: i got answere my self